# I need an Excel Macro that copies a range to a new range and renames named ranges within the new range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet named Progress and in it I have a range (C5:C56). 
In C5 I have entered Wk1. 
In C6 I have entered Wk2. 
This sequence continues until Wk52 is in C56.

In D5:E5 I have formulas which reference named ranges. 
In D5 I have the formula =COUNT(Wk1CountTrainingSessions).
In E6 I have the formula =Wk1HrsTraining

I need a macro that copies the range D5:E5 down to D6:E6 and then changes the named ranges in the formulas in range D6:E6 from starting with Wk1 to starting with Wk2.

i would like to be able to repeat this for every subsequent week of training.
e.g for Wk3 the Macro will copy D6:E6 to D7:E7 and change the named ranges in the formulas to start with Wk3.

I tried this code and it doesnt work

```
    Sub ChangeNamedRangesOnProgressSheet()

Dim RangeName As Name
Dim RangeName2 As String
Dim NewRangeName As String
Dim j As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Progress As Worksheet


Worksheets("Progress").Range("D5:E5").Copy _
    Destination:=Worksheets("Progress").Range("D6:E6")

'''''   Delete invalid named ranges
For Each RangeName In ws.Names
    If InStr(1, RangeName.RefersTo, "#REF!") > 0 Then
        RangeName.Delete
    End If
Next RangeName


j = Range("C6")
For Each RangeName In Worksheet.Progress
        If InStr(1, RangeName, "Wk1", 1) > 0 Then
            NewRangeName = Replace(RangeName.Name, "Wk1", j)
            RangeName2 = Replace(RangeName, "='Wk1'", j)

    Next RangeName
    j = j.Offset(1)

MsgBox "Done"
```

I also have tried this code which is similar to Karthicks suggestion in the comments in the psot below. it doesnt work either

```
Sub test()

Dim i As Long
Dim CountTrainingSessions As String
Dim HrsTraining As String
Dim Wk As String

    For i = 5 To 56
  Range("D" & i).Value = Range("Wk" & i & "CountTrainingSessions").Count
  Range("E" & i).Value = Range("Wk" & i & "HrsTraining")
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: The second code works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope you looking for this

```
Sub test()
    For i = 5 To 56
        Range("D" & i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Range("C" & i) & CountTrainingSessions)
        Range("E" & i).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Count(Range("C" & i) & HrsTraining)
    Next i
End Sub
```

if you need formula please try the below

```
Sub test()
    Dim i As Long 
    Dim CountTrainingSessions As String
    Dim HrsTraining As String
    For i = 5 To 56
        Range("D" & i).Formula = "=Count(" & Range("C" & i) & "CountTrainingSessions)"
        Range("E" & i).Formula = "=Count(" & Range("C" & i) & "HrsTraining)"
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for reply but its not working. Its deleting the formulas in the cells and results in 0 values in all the cells

Comment: what is  wk1CountTrainingSessions and wk1HrsTraining?

Comment: Wk1(CountTrainingSessions) is a range on the Wk1 worksheet. Wk1TrainingHrs is a cell on the Wk1 Worksheet. i tried this code but it doesnt work either Sub test()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim CountTrainingSessions As String
    Dim HrsTraining As String
    Dim Wk As String
    
    
    
    For i = 5 To 56
        Range("D" & i).Value = Range("Wk" & i & "CountTrainingSessions").Count
        Range("E" & i).Value = Range("Wk" & i & "HrsTraining")
    Next i
End Sub

Comment: i have option explicit set for all variables so you will need to decalre the variables in your code

Comment: Thanks, your second code worked but only if the variables are declared

Comment: Edit your code by decalring the varaibles like this Sub test()
    
  Dim i As Long
    Dim CountTrainingSessions As String
    Dim HrsTraining As String
    
    For i = 5 To 56
        Range("D" & i).Formula = "=Count(" & Range("C" & i) & "CountTrainingSessions)"
        Range("E" & i).Formula = "=Sum(" & Range("C" & i) & "HrsTraining)"
    Next i
End Sub